# Symfony 2 Custom User Provider & Authentication

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a project where a segment of the site is secured. The credentials for the users who auth are stored in QuickBase (an online database with a custom API) and the passwords are encrypted using a custom hash.

Can someone give me a high-level take on what classes I will need to build and implement to support authenticating these users from a web service and using my own password hash mechanism?

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/account
            provider: quickbase_users
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    providers:
        quickbase_users:
            id: quickbase_user_provider

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Here are my routes:

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: JMLWebsiteBundle:Security:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

I'm currently getting this error after submitting a user/pass at /login:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
```

Comment: You sould add `anonymous`, `logout` and what's the most important `form_login` properties to your `secured_area` firewall. See: [Using a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form)

Comment: I accidentally left them out of the post, but they are added. Still getting /login_check controller not found.

Comment: `login/check_path` should be children of `form_login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your User class that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`.
2. Create a custom encoder service:

   1. Create a service that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface`
   2. Register that service as encoder for your User class in `security.yml`:

      ```
      security:
          encoders:
              MyCustomBundle\Entity\User:  # Class/interface from point #1
                  id: my.encoder.service   # Service id from point #2.1
      ```
3. Create a custom user provider:

   1. Create a service that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface`
   2. Register that service as user provider in `security.yml`:

      ```
      security:
          [...]

          providers:
              my_custom_user_provider:
                  id: my.user_provider.service # Service id from point #3.1
      ```

Check out [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) to see an example of implementation of custom user provider.

Comment: I have the User and User Provider. Don't I also need a custom authentication provider somewhere?

Comment: Could you describe auth process? Is there a form with username/password fields? If there is, you won't need custom entry point/auth provider.

Comment: Yes - just a basic username and password field. Could you post what a sample security.yml might look like for this scenario?

Comment: Also, can you speak to the role of the User class and User provider? Which one do I actually validate the submitted $username and $password against the db?

Comment: That should be everthing you need, please edit your question and post what have you tried. Among `encoders` and `providers` your `security.yml` file should contain `firewalls` (you should define at least one with `form_login` entry point), `role_hierarhy` and `access_control` - see Symfony's docs.

Comment: UserProvider tries to load user data (id, username, password, firstName - in other words User object (which implements UserInterface)). Encoder is responsible for encoding password from form. The authentication itself is done elsewhere (by `form_login` entry point), but you don't have to handle that in this case.

Comment: I have added some additional information. I've got everything (aside from the encoder) implemented, but am getting a /login_check controller error. Any ideas?